# How to check if a sequence in a tuple is part of a tuple? python

Tags: python, tuples, sequence

This might be a silly question, but is it possible to check whether the elements in a tuple1 are a subset of another tuple2 *in the same sequence* as they appear in tuple1? I tried to do this with .issubset, but this does not look at whether the sequence of tuple1 is in tuple 2:

```
tuple1 = ([1, 2, 3])
tuple2 = ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
set(tuple1).issubset(tuple2)
True

tuple1 = ([1, 2, 3])
tuple2 = ([1, 3, 2, 4, 5])
set(tuple1).issubset(tuple2)
True                         # Only membership is considered, not sequence
```

What I would like is:

```
tuple1 = ([1, 2, 3])
tuple2 = ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
(tuple1).sequenceisin(tuple2)
True

tuple1 = ([1, 2, 3])
tuple2 = ([1, 3, 2, 4, 5])
(tuple1).sequenceisin(tuple2)
False
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You have a tuple with a list inside it! Is that intentional?

Comment: Actually it's not even a tuple as written- it's just a list.

Comment: Yes, that is intentional. Tuple1 actually contains many such list/ sequences which I want to test on tuple2.

Comment: actually, he doesn't have a tuple. when you have only one element inside the  parentheses the item will not be a tuple unless you use a trailing comma

Comment: tuples or lists it's a duplicate.

Comment: Yes you are correct, my mistake!